# Python ttk.treeview widget drag and drop issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk, ttkwidgets

I managed to setup dragging and dropping for items inside a ttk.treeview widget, in which I intend to add an image.

The dragging and dropping works, however when I select two consecutive items using the shift+LMB click, and then try dragging them, they shuffle positions chaotically.

I have no idea why and need to fix this.

All help appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk
from tkinter.ttk import *

def bDown_Shift(event):
    wref = event.widget
    select = [wref.index(s) for s in wref.selection()]
    select.append(wref.index(wref.identify_row(event.y)))
    select.sort()
    for i in range(select[0],select[-1]+1,1):
        wref.selection_add(wref.get_children()[i])

def bDown(event):
    wref = event.widget
    if wref.identify_row(event.y) not in wref.selection():
        wref.selection_set(wref.identify_row(event.y))    

def bUp(event):
    wref = event.widget
    if wref.identify_row(event.y) in wref.selection():
        wref.selection_set(wref.identify_row(event.y))    

def bUp_Shift(event):
    pass

def bMove(event):
    wref = event.widget
    moveto = wref.index(wref.identify_row(event.y))    
    for s in wref.selection():
        wref.move(s, '', moveto)

root = tk.Tk()

tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=("col1","col2"), 
                    displaycolumns="col2", 
                    selectmode='none')

# insert some items into the tree
for i in range(10):
    tree.insert('', 'end',iid='line%i' % i, text='line:%s' % i, values=('', i))

tree.grid()
tree.bind("<ButtonPress-1>",bDown)
tree.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",bUp, add='+')
tree.bind("<B1-Motion>",bMove, add='+')
tree.bind("<Shift-ButtonPress-1>",bDown_Shift, add='+')
tree.bind("<Shift-ButtonRelease-1>",bUp_Shift, add='+')

root.mainloop()
```

Please try this code, select two items using shift click, and dragging them up or down.

Comment: presumably, whichever one is loaded first.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems in your `bMove` function:

1. You shouldn't reorder when `moveto` is inside your selection
2. Wether you move up or down, the insertion might reverse your selection order. Handle these cases separately:

```
def bMove(event):
    wref = event.widget
    selection = wref.selection()
    selection_index = [wref.index(s) for s in selection]
    moveto = wref.index(wref.identify_row(event.y))
    if moveto < min(selection_index): # moving up
        for s in selection[::-1]:
            wref.move(s, '', moveto)
    elif moveto > max(selection_index): # moving down
        for s in selection:
            wref.move(s, '', moveto)
```

With this code your can drag more than two items.